# Shorthand for isset($var['foo']) ? $var['foo'] : ''

Tags: php

I feel like I write this a lot in PHP:

```
 $val = isset($var['foo']) ? $var['foo'] : '';
```

Is there a shorter way to write this? I can't use the ternary operator because the conditional is an `isset` check, not the value of the function itself.

Comment: I toyed around with using `filter_var()` but that isn't any shorter really. Never got around to doing speed test on it. Benjamin's answer is your best bet.

Comment: The most simple way is merely `$val = @$var['foo'];`. You may look at my [previous answer at a similar question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/85969/69690) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap it in a function (check the syntax, I don't actually know PHP):

```
function getDefault($array, $key, $default) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post that! :)  (And your syntax is correct, though I would probably do `function getDefault(array $array, $key, $default)`.

Answer (score 14):

Now three years later we have the [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) in PHP7:

```
 $val = $var['foo'] ?? '';
```

http://3v4l.org/Kcb2A

Comment: That's awesome! About time ;) I wonder how long it's going to take for most servers to get updated to PHP7 and have it be the main standard at least people on shared hosts. Time for me to look into updating my system.

Comment: Note that it is still in beta phase (currently beta 3).

Answer (score 6):

Building off of what Benjamin Kloster has

If you pass the parameter by reference instead of value it will not choke trying to pass in an invalid index.

```
function getDefault(&$isset, $default) {
    return isset($isset) ? $isset : $default;
}
```

Or if you want a dynamic amount of parameters to default to

Just don't pass in any unknown indexes for them because I'm not sure how to do dynamic parameters as reference if that's even possible

ie: getDefault("default", $notSet, $stillNotSet, "isSet");

```
function getDefault($default, &$isset)
{
    $argCount = func_num_args();
    if ($argCount < 3)
        return isset($isset) ? $isset : $default;
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $argCount; $i++)
        {
            $arg = func_get_arg($i);
            if (isset($arg))
                return $arg;
        }
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Return is missing in else statement. Why do you start loop from 2nd argument?

Comment: @Andy that's a good point I'm sure my updated code would include that so I will update this answer to include that; good catch : ) It's been a while since I wrote this so I'm not sure if I had a reason but that's also a good catch I will update ; )

Comment: Too bad this won't work for multiple arguments. it throws a notice when calling getDefault with bunch of non-existing variables, apparently because only the first argument is passed by ref.

Comment: @Andy unfortunately there's no way to pass any given amount of parameters all as reference from what my last research concluded.

Comment: You can drop else statement completely and just leave isset($isset) ? $isset : $default;. PHP 7 solves that disaster with ?? operator.

Comment: I just switched the parameters around so that default is the first parameter, thus if nothing is set with any amount of parameters it will always grab the first parameter as the default.

Yeah I've heard talk about PHP 7 being out and was just wondering if it introduced something to help with this issue ;)

I'm not sure if the if($argCount < 3) short circuit is a shortcut that will save time, you could always strip it out and just have the for loop in the function.

Last I remember the passing by reference was important for arrays and invalid indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27028/discussion-between-cts-ae-and-andy).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is

```
$foo = ''; // default value
extract($var); // extracts all array items to corresponding variables
```

This is not appropriate in all cases, eg. when:

- You don't want to extract all array elements, just one
- You want to extract the variable to a different name (it's possible to specify a prefix though, so the item will extract to $prefix_foo)
- You don't want to pollute your name space

But in other cases it's quite neat and clean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something fancier that supports nested structures, like such:

```
$foo = json_decode('{"bar":[42]}');
echo getDefault( $foo, '-default-', 'bar', 0 );
# 42
echo getDefault( $foo, '-default-', 'bar', 1 );
# -default-
echo getDefault( $foo, '-default-', 'missing' );
# -default-
```

... consider:

```
function getDefault( $container, $default /*, key1, key2 */ ) {
    // get all remaining arguments
    $keys = array_slice( func_get_args(), 2 );

    while( $keys ) {
        $key = array_shift( $keys );
        if( is_array( $container ) && isset( $container[ $key ] ) ) {
            $container = $container[ $key ];
        } else if( is_object( $container ) && isset( $container->$key ) ) {
            $container = $container->$key;
        } else {
            return $default;
        }
    }

    return $container;
}
```